# C Code -- Pthread Not Compiling

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I'm having trouble compiling my code, which uses a mutex (so uses pthread locks and conditions). I've tried including the header file, compiling with -pthread or -lpthread, but I'm still getting an error. Help would be much appreciated.

This is the error output:

**implicit declaration of function ‘Pthread_mutex_lock’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  Pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); //locked
     ^
/tmp/cchVS47i.o: In function `getMessage1':
hw3.c:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to`Pthread_mutex_lock'
hw3.c:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `Pthread_mutex_lock'
/tmp/cchVS47i.o: In function`getMessage2':
hw3.c:(.text+0x13e): undefined reference to `Pthread_mutex_lock'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status**

And here's relevant sections of my code (edited for clarity):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char message[1001];
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t condition = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void *getMessage1()
{
Pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); //locked

 ....
}

int main(void)
{
pthread_t id1;
pthread_t id2;

pthread_create((&id1), NULL, getMessage1, NULL);
pthread_create((&id2), NULL, getMessage2, NULL);

...

return 0;
}
```

Comment: have you given library as argument

Comment: what do you mean by argument? I've tried compiling with variations of gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread hw3.c -lpthread

Comment: i thought you didn't include library

Comment: so do you have any other suggestions to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the capital P you have in

> Pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); //locked

in the beginning of the function getmessage1().

Your compiler is complaining that it has not seen a declaration for that function in the compiling phase. Also it is complaining about that in the linking phase. You are including all the right libraries because it is not complaining about any of the other functions that are correctly typed.

The correct name of the function is pthread_mutex_lock().

In original k&r C it is possible to use functions without declarations, although compilers warn about them. In more modern versions of C (99) this has been deprecated.

Comment: thank you, but I actually still get an error. when I remove the capital p and compile with  gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread hw3.c -lpthread
I get:           warning: implicit declaration of function ‘thread_mutex_lock’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     thread_mutex_lock(&lock); //locked
/tmp/ccGZwoMv.o: In function `getMessage2':
(.text+0x134): undefined reference to `thread_mutex_lock'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Change it to a small p, don't remove it completely. The correct name of the function is pthread_mutex_lock().

Comment: It does not seem like you changed it to a small p since the last warning you posted is complaining about 'thread_mutex_lock()' without a p in the beginning.

Comment: I literally changed every occurrence to pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

Comment: I take that back. There was one 'thread.' However, this is the new error I'm getting.

Comment: Never mind! The error was actually as a result of my trying to change something. When I changed it back & removed the one 'thread,' it finally compiled. Thank you so much.